# What is the word or process of an outcast becoming a hero or savior?

Tags: word-choice

John is an outcast, but by saving her life, became a hero. What is a word to describe John, or a word to describe the process of him transitioning from an outcast to a hero?

The context in which this word will be used is in a story involving John (an outcast) being placed into a zombie-infested world, and through his actions, building up an establishment that thrives under the conditions, and becoming a savior in the eyes of the people.

Comment: Are you sure you mean *castaway*? Please check a dictionary and edit (or just check a thesaurus which should make the question unnecessary).

Comment: My mistake, I've fixed the question.

Comment: *Rehabilitation? Redemption? Expiation? Atonement?* I think we need more context.

Comment: I've added some more details to the description.

Comment: @FumbleFingers also we need the OP to consult a thesaurus and tell us what's wrong with those suggestions or ask us which one is right.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could say that John was “***redeemed***” by his saving act.

> [**redeem**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=redeemed+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=redeemed+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l4j0i10.0.0.7.275344...........0.YvulU_Q10QM&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: **1**. compensate for the faults or bad aspects of (something). "a disappointing debate *redeemed* only by an outstanding speech"
>
> *synonyms*: save, compensate for the defects of, vindicate; see, Google

Or, that John was “***transfigured***”.

> [**transfigured**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=transfigured+definition&gws_rd=ssl) *transitive verb*: transform into something more beautiful or elevated. "the world is made luminous and is *transfigured*";
>
> *synonyms*: transform, transmute, change, alter, metamorphose; see, Google

Comment: Vindication sounds fantastic.

Comment: Vindication would imply John was always in the right.  Redemption implies he was in the wrong, and reformed.

Comment: I am speaking of vindication from the people's perspective, they vindicated John. In a sense, the world vindicated John.